# Restore local extension data after chrome reinstall

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I had some issues recently with a chrome update and tried fixing it myself, however afterwards it said all my extensions needed to be repaired. When actually doing the repair though it just reinstalled the extension and got rid of any of the local data (eg. tampermonkey scripts, ublock block lists).

Is there any way to restore this extension data in a way that chrome loads it again without issue? (I have a copy of my entire userdata folder from before this happened; I just need to know what folders and files I should copy to make chrome not tell me they are corrupt again while still getting their data back)

Comment: +1 for actually having a backup to work from. Soooo many questioners on here don't :\

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can restore the entire Chrome profile by
restoring the folder
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.

This will restore all your personal data, bookmarks and extensions.

Save the current contents of the folder before restoring it,
in case something goes wrong.

Comment: This is what I had done to fix the browser issue, and everything EXCEPT my extensions worked. I need some way to import the extension data specifically so it doesnt go on about how it thinks my extensions are corrupted and then forces me to delete it again.

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Please add a screenshot of `chrome://extensions/`. Do you have a "Repair" option next to the extension's name and does it help?

Comment: It says "! This extension may have been corrupted." and where the slider to enable/disable would be is now replaced with a blue button saying "Repair". Clicking the button is of no help as I described within the original question, since it just reinstalls it and deletes any local data that used to exist for it.

Comment: You could experiment with repairing one particular extension and return selectively from backup its data from the sub-folders whose names are `Local Extension Settings` or that start with `Extension`. If you find a folder that will restore your extension data, then do the same for the other extensions. That's as far as I can advise.